# ListTile's tileColor and selectedTileColor are not working in Flutter / Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have upgraded `Flutter` version on my `Windows 10` system. **`flutter upgrade` command installed Flutter's 2.5.0-5.2.pre version on system.**

My existing project has many `ListTile` widgets on various screens / pages. I am attaching below  code snippets.

**Code 1:**

```
ListTile(
  tileColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 0, 1),
  selected: true,
  selectedTileColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 0, 255, 1),
  title: Text('Hello friends'),
),
```

**Code 2:**

```
ListTile(
  tileColor: Colors.green,
  selected: true,
  selectedTileColor: Colors.red,
  title: Text('Hello friends'),
),
```

Is there anyone who can help me to understand why are ListTile's `tileColor` and `selectedTileColor` not working in Flutter / Dart after upgrading flutter? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

**For reference:**

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 2.5.0-5.2.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1165], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[√] VS Code (version 1.60.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
```

Comment: Why don't you run the commands the flutter doctor tells you?

Comment: @stacktrace2234 Thank you for your quick reply. I have solved all the flutter doctor issues but listtile's tilecolor and selectedtilecolor not working issue is still persist, any other suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Kamlesh any luck solving this issue? It is driving me crazy. It is not working with me.